# installing WF into VS 2008 Express

Tags: .net, visual-studio, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to install WF with VS2008E.

That's what I already did:

1. Go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx
2. "Get it" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd980558.aspx
3. "Get the Windows Software Development Kit" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx
4. Select first link at Downloads (due to I'm using windows 7) "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1" http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=150217&clcid=0x409
5. Download DVD ISO and install it

So SDK installed successfully, but I can't find new project type at VS and WF examples provided with SDK doesn't opened, because they references to not exists WF.

So where I was wrong and how to do what I need?

Thank you.

**UPD**:
So, seems like I was wrong thinking Express supporting WF :-(

Comment: The World Wildlife Fund is *very* protective of its WWF trademark. As MS found out shortly after Windows Workflow Foundation was announced. So it is know as "WF".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are no project templates in the Windows SDK.  Note that the web page "recommends" downloading the VS2008 Professional Trial Edition.  Yes, that would work, it has WF project templates.

Comment: As I added to UPD - Express didn't support WWF Visuals. It's some weird hacks to use WWF libraries itself but without visuals, it is absolutely useless. thanks for answer